# FFMPEG not getting a smooth video

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to record my screen using ffmpeg but i am  not getting  a smooth video. Below is the command line code used. I am using windows 10;

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop output.mp4
```

is there is any extra setting to get a good video

Currently output video is playing like missing frames

Comment: Show the complete log.

Comment: @llogan thanks!..actually i didn't noticed the log before, there is a warning that  -Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize-  so i increased it and now it is ok

Answer (score 2):

I myself found the answer, I changed the code like below

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 24 -probesize 42M -i desktop -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p camera1.mp4
```

Actual i had a warning "Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize" so i increased the probesize and added the ultrafast preset.

Now it is recording with good quality...